What tool has a ring on the end of a threaded handle shaft?
Does anyone know what this is? I got it in a box lot of tools. The handle reads "General Tool USA".


Looks a bit like a nut splitter.

It's a punch and chisel holder. You use it to hold a metal punch, so that you can keep your fingers away from the action in case you miss with the hammer.
Here's a YouTube video showing how it's used.

Thank you Cheery! great eye.  Man... I have busted my knuckles more than once without this tool... Ha!

Could have a dual use as a tool that you could slip over the end of a pipe, and by turning the handle, would work as a set screw.

Would be much more useful for that if it were somehow an openable ring, so you could put it around a pipe which doesn't have a free end.  There are tools which are designed for this of course.

That nub feels like hard plastic or Teflon... probably would not grab well
